# Can I avoid a loop for writing the same value in a continous subset of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a program where I repeat a succession of methods to reproduce time evolution. One of the things I have to do is to write the same value for a long continue subset of elements of a very large array. Knowing which elements are and which value I want, is there any other way rather than doing a loop for setting these values each by each?

EDIT: To be clear, I want to avoid this:

```
double arr[10000000];
int i;

for (i=0; i<100000; ++i)    
    arr[i] = 1;
```

by just one single call if it is possible. Can you assign to a part of an array the values from another array of the same size? Maybe I could have in memory a second array arr2[1000000] with all elements 1 and then do something like copying the memory of arr2 to the first 100.000 elements of arr?

Comment: Need to see some code to understand what is happening.

Comment: You want `memset()`

Comment: Only if that value is a single byte, though. (And of course, that's effectively a loop, too, just not one you typed yourself.)

Comment: Based on the sketchy information you've given us, a loop sounds exactly right.  Is there some reason you don't want to use one?

Comment: Because I need to do the same loop an average of 80.000 times and the array can be of a total size of 10⁷ elements. I was wondering this to avoid wasting the time.

Comment: If setting it takes that long it might be better to avoid the need to set it at all. How to do that, and whether it would be a good idea would depend on your specific application though

Comment: How will you avoid "wasting time", if you have physically to set a value of this memory anyway? Well, that's certainly sounds as an XY-problem.

Comment: Don't worry about the "time waste" and implement this with your loop, I wouldn't be surprised if it took only some microseconds.

Comment: If you're setting 1, just do memset. It's already a tuned version of what you want to do anyway as part of libc.

Comment: @LucasHolt Won't work for doubles.

Comment: Good point.. hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it was just faster to copy a chunk of memory rather than summing an index and accessing to that specifically element each time. Just asking because I needed to set a continuous subset. Never thought about this.

Comment: Maybe you better describe the underlying problem?

Comment: May I ask why do you set it with 1 specifically?

Comment: Eugene: Sorry but I cannot understand you. I think I explained well the problem. Is just an optimization of the process. SHG: Because my problem requires to be a value that in this moment, I consider it has to be 1.0.

Comment: Fundamentally, if you have 100,000 doubles that you want to set to 1.0, there is no way around the fact that you are going to have to perform 100,000 assignments.  If that's the situation, a simple loop like the one you've written is the best way.  If there's some fancy low-level optimization, a good, modern compiler will be able to employ it for you automatically, as long as you state your intentions clearly, i.e. with a nice, simple loop.

Comment: Sometimes, a different data structure is more appropriate.  Rather than an array, you may want to have a tree data structure of some kind, that lets you explicitly -- and compactly -- say things like "cells 100001 to 200000" are all 1.0".  But it won't be a simple array, and looking values up in it will be more elaborate.  So another question you have to ask yourself is, does it need to be more efficient to set M number of cells to 1.0, or to do N number of lookups later?

Comment: Can't you set it with `0`s and then every time you read the value you'd interpret the 0 as 1? Because if you can - problem solved and you can use memset(0)

Comment: @Learningfrommasters I will explain you what I mean. Your original problem might sound like "return a sum of 10000000 ones". Then you can think - OK, I will set 10000000 memory variables to one and sum them up. Obviously, this solution is ridiculous, but it will face the same problem as yours. I am not saying your case is ridiculous as well, but you might miss some much simpler solution to the *real* problem.

Comment: Sorry but in my problem I can't, SHG. Ok Steve, then there's nothing more here :) Just asking because sometimes, you learn things in c that are not very frequent to use and you don't know.

Comment: If you wanted to be very fancy (and lose portability) with a solution that is somewhat similar to the `memset` solutions above, you *could* write your first double to the start of the array, then `memcpy` that 8 bytes to the location of the start of your array + 8 bytes. Now `memcpy` both doubles to the next location, so you have 4 doubles. Now `memcpy` all four doubles to the next location, so you have 8 doubles...and so on.

(It would look pretty bizarre and it probably won't be faster than a simple loop)

Comment: @struthersneil That is very cute.  You're right, it probably won't be any faster (although, actually, it might be).  But still, very cute.  I like it.

Comment: @SHG turns out it was about twice as fast on the system I tested it on. I'll drop it in as an answer for a lark.

Comment: You can use threads to get speed up.

Comment: Maybe start with a large const array of double '1', to save the inefficient early stages of copying small ranges?

Comment: ..adn then chop up the array and give each clump to a thread, as suggested by @TanveerBadar ?

Comment: We can do this. We can *make this happen.*

Comment: Although have fun multi-threading your C app. You have my blessings to proceed forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a somewhat tongue-in-cheek and non-portable possibility for you to consider. If you tailored your buffer to a size that is a power of 2, you could seed the buffer with a single double, then use `memcpy` to copy successively larger chunks of the buffer until the buffer is full.

So first you copy the first 8 bytes over the next 8 bytes...(so now you have 2 doubles)

...then you copy the first 16 bytes over the next 16 bytes...(so now you have 4 doubles)

...then you copy the first 32 bytes over the next 32 bytes...(so now you have 8 doubles)

...and so on.

It's plain to see that we won't actually call `memcpy` all that many times, and if the implementation of `memcpy` is sufficiently faster than a simple loop we'll see a benefit.

Try building and running this and tell me how it performs on your machine. It's a very scrappy proof of concept...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void loop_buffer_init(double* buffer, int buflen, double val)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
  {
    buffer[i] = val;
  }
}

void memcpy_buffer_init(double* buffer, int buflen, double val)
{
  buffer[0] = val;

  int half_buf_size = buflen * sizeof(double) / 2;
  for (int i = sizeof(double); i <= half_buf_size; i += i)
  {
    memcpy((unsigned char *)buffer + i, buffer, i);
  }
}

void check_success(double* buffer, int buflen, double expected_val)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
  {
    if (buffer[i] != expected_val)
    {
      printf("But your whacky loop failed horribly.\n");
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  const int TEST_REPS = 500;
  const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16777216;
  static double buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // 2**24 doubles, 128MB

  time_t start_time;
  time(&start_time);
  printf("Normal loop starting...\n");

  for (int reps = 0; reps < TEST_REPS; reps++)
  {
    loop_buffer_init(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 1.0);
  }

  time_t end_time;
  time(&end_time);
  printf("Normal loop finishing after %.f seconds\n", 
         difftime(end_time, start_time));

  time(&start_time);
  printf("Whacky loop starting...\n");

  for (int reps = 0; reps < TEST_REPS; reps++)
  {
    memcpy_buffer_init(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 2.5);
  }

  time(&end_time);
  printf("Whacky loop finishing after %.f seconds\n", 
         difftime(end_time, start_time));

  check_success(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 2.5);
}
```

On my machine, the results were:

```
Normal loop starting...
Normal loop finishing after 21 seconds
Whacky loop starting...
Whacky loop finishing after 9 seconds
```

To work with a buffer that was less than a perfect power of 2 in size, just go as far as you can with the increasing powers of 2 and then fill out the remainder in one final `memcpy`.

(Edit: before anyone mentions it, *of course* this is pointless with a static double (might as well initialize it at compile time) but it'll work just as well with a nice fresh stretch of memory requested at runtime.)

It looks like this solution is *very sensitive to your cache size* or other hardware optimizations. On my old (circa 2009) laptop the `memcpy` solution is as slow or slower than the simple loop, until the buffer size drops below 1MB. Below 1MB or so the `memcpy` solution returns to being twice as fast.

Comment: I tried it on my machine and got about the same times (23 and 11 s).  I suggest changing `<cstring>` and `<ctime>` to `<string.h>` and `<time.h>`.

Comment: But, note to OP: at this rate, the 100,000 initializations you asked about would only take about 0.14 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot!

Comment: Oh yeah OP, that's why I needed to loop 500 times. You probably shouldn't worry about this unless your circumstances are pretty bizarre.

Comment: Yikes, I didn't even notice the extra loop!  (I thought 0.14s was a little slow.)  So, correction: At this rate the 100,000 initializations you asked about would only take about 0.0003 seconds, that is, 0.3 milliseconds or 250 microseconds.  (Give or take.  YMMV.)

Comment: Goaaarrnnn.. someone try it with two threads doing half the array each, (even better two from a pool that just need signaling, rather than creating). :)

Comment: Those are illustrative 8s for illustrative purposes :)

Comment: Fair enough.  (I do that sometimes, too.)

Comment: Alright, I went full pedantry mode and swapped out those magic numbers. There's no tests to make sure the `memcpy` operation does nothing silly, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Interestingly, the `memcpy` solution was about 50% slower than the simple loop solution on my old laptop. It looks like `memcpy` is subject to hardware optimizations on newer machines.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's probably very sensitive to cache size.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a program where I repeat a succession of methods to reproduce
>   time evolution. One of the things I have to do is to write the same
>   value for a long continue subset of elements of a very large array.
>   Knowing which elements are and which value I want, is there any other
>   way rather than doing a loop for setting these values each by each?

In principle, you can *initialize* an array however you like without using a loop.  If that array has static duration then that initialization might in fact be extremely efficient, as the initial value is stored in the executable image in one way or another.

Otherwise, you have a few options:

- if the array elements are of a character type then you can use `memset()`.  Very likely this involves a loop internally, but you won't have one literally in your own code.
- if the representation of the value you want to set has all bytes equal, such as is the case for typical representations of 0 in any arithmetic type , then `memset()` is again a possibility.
- as you suggested, if you have another array with suitable contents then you can copy some or all of it into the target array.  For this you would use `memcpy()`, unless there is a chance that the source and destination could overlap, in which case you would want `memmove()`.
- more generally, you may be able to read in the data from some external source, such as a file (e.g. via `fread()`).  Don't count on any I/O-based solution to be performant, however.
- you can write an analog of `memset()` that is specific to the data type of the array.  Such a function would likely need to use a loop of some form internally, but you could avoid such a loop in the caller.
- you can write a macro that expands to the needed loop.  This can be type-generic, so you don't need different versions for different data types.  It uses a loop, but the loop would not appear literally in your source code at the point of use.
- If you know in advance how many elements you want to set, then in principle, you could write that many assignment statements without looping.  But I cannot imagine why you would want so badly to avoid looping that you would resort to this for a large number of elements.

All of those except the last actually *do* loop, however -- they just avoid cluttering your code with a loop construct at the point where you want to set the array elements.  Some of them may also be clearer and more immediately understandable to human readers.